# Keeping a reference to a vector element

Tags: c++, vector, struct, vertex

So I have 2 big vectors, one called V of struct vertex and one called contractions of struct vertex_pair (representing  2 neighbors by their indices and a specific value called delta).

What part of my algorithm has to do is to take a specific vertex v and change the delta value of all contractions with one of the vertices being v.
At first I tried to go over the entire contractions vector and check every single one, but that's really inefficient.

So I tried extending the vertex struct so that it saves a list of pointers to all contractions consisting of that vertex. Problem is that I need to sort the contractions vector, which fricks up all the references.

Anyone has an idea on how to save the neighbors of a vertex so that I can write-access them or any better way to implement that?

Comment: Please add some code illustrating your problem.

Comment: Seems like you need a level of indirection. For example, a map of vertex_pair indexes per vertex (that you need to update when you sort your contractions). Or a map of vertex_pair indexes that you sort instead of the contractions itself.